# Computing a truncated Hessenberg decomposition

Tags: matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

I'm working on a linear algebra problem where I am given a real, symmetric matrix A. For any such matrix, we can compute its Hessenberg decomposition, A = QHQ^T, where Q is an orthogonal matrix and H is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix. My goal is to extract the matrix elements of H.

This is already implemented in scipy with the function `scipy.linalg.Hessenberg()`. Unfortunately, the matrix A in my problem can be extremely large (millions of entries) and full Hessenberg reduction is difficult; fortunately it is sufficient to access a relatively small number of matrix elements of H, say the first 10,000 elements of each diagonal. So I would like to perform what I'm calling a truncated Hessenberg decomposition: I just want to perform the first N steps of Hessenberg reduction, where N is an argument I'll pass to an eventual function.

Is there a simple way to implement such a code? I've looked at the source for the scipy function referenced above and can't begin to understand what it is doing (I have no experience with lapack). I would rather not write my own version since it will undoubtedly be slower than the scipy version, so any comments on how this might be done beginning from the scipy code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Is your matrix sparse?

Comment: It is. I had also considered using the Lanczos algorithm for that reason, but I know it often has numerical stability issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is, but if you can get the same information from an SVD, then `scipy.sparse` has an SVD implementation that could be useful.

Comment: I don't see how I can use SVDs for this but thanks for your comment. The motivation for this problem comes from physics, and I'm not sure it helps to get into those details here.

Comment: Right. There is obviously physical interpretation that can be gained from the SVD, but I wasn't sure if it would work for this application. If `scipy.sparse` doesn't have an implementation, then I guess that leaves you with two options: (1) find a package that can do what you need or (2) write your own function that can be applied to submatrices (assuming the decomposition holds for submatrices).

Comment: Right I agree. So far I've had no luck finding a package that does this. As for submatrices, the algorithm decimates another row/column in each iteration, so stopping after a finite number of steps is possible. I was just hoping to take advantage of optimized methods...